# How to create a multimodal network?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network, multimodal-network

How to add waterways and railroads without turn restrictions into the previously created street network dataset  with turn restrictions, in order to create a multimodal network?

For a university project, we use TeleAtlas Multinet data. We used the following Street Data Processing Tool: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=755f96fcde454ece8f790fecb3e031c7

Street Network is created with all kinds of turn restrictions, then now we need to add waterways and railroads into the routable network with global turns. However we couldn't create the multimodal network. Could you please give a suggestion if you have an idea about this topic.

Comment: What errors/problems have you encountered?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to have only meta nodes representing inter-modal transfer points cause modeling this network with access at every node-intersection would be meaningless for routing and analysis.

You could use coding so that different feature classes could only be accessed by a certain flag at inter-modal points. Create metadata object oriented models of intersection, say, edges going to or from an intersection point and allow processing only on correctly set flags for your particular analytic case. Use batch processing to convert features to OOP models such as if A = street route, B = Railroute, C = Inter modal transfer then where routes = A to B via C = route any valid combination = routing network for that particular case in as many different associations and cases subject to procedural rules as you want to allow.